# Find float in dataFrame using a For loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop

I have a function that i will iterate through to find the first instance of a floating number and then print 'we hit profit'. In the case below, i would like to find 8.49 from the WAP column and stop looking. I get the error message: 
for x in profit_Price:
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

```
profit_Price = round((Wap_price * 0.020) + Wap_price,2)

def profit_stop(x):

    for x in profit_Price:
        if x == 8.49:
            print('we hit profit')
    else:
        return x

#calls the above function 'profit_stop'
df['WAP'].apply(profit_stop)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. `apply` runs the function given on each element separately, that is - for each number `num` in `df['WAP']` it will run  `profit_stop(num)`. There is no way to stop apply in the middle (except raising `Exception`)

Comment: So how should i apply logical testing to the WAP column in the dataframe. Do i need to create a list from the column and then iterate through it?

Comment: Any logical operation on `pandas.Series` is element-wise operation. Try `df['WAP'] == 8.49` and see what happens. Then try `df[df['WAP'] == 8.49]`

Comment: Though you'll better be off with `df[np.isclose(df['WAP'], 8.49)]` (because float comparison is not always 100% accurate)

Comment: I see that one will return True/False and row number. The second returns the entire row where WAP has 8.49 in it. But when i use the var name profit_Price, i get 'Empty DataFrame'. profit_Price is <class 'numpy.float64'>. I am trying to find the first row that has my profit_Price in the WAP column. I also expect my WAP column won't always contain my profit_Price and i will be searching the WAP column for a stop_loss value that is lower than my profit_Price. if we reached profit_Price show the first row that happend. If we didn't reach profit_Price, show row where we hit stop_loss.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want either the first row where `profit_Price == 8.49`, and if not, then the last row in the `series`?

(If you've done `df[profit_Price == 8.49]` and it returned you empty dataframe, it means that there are no locations where `profit_Price` is 8.49. You could do `df[profit_Price <= 8.49]` to get all rows where `profit_Price` is smaller or equal to 8.49)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your purpose is comparison, you should not worry about stopping (unless your `DataFrame` is really huge). `pandas` relies on `numpy` comparison which is really efficient and will run faster than a Python `for` loop.

Running `df['WAP'] == 8.49` or `np.close(df['WAP'], 8.49)` will return a boolean array (`True`/`False`) for each element in the `series`. You can use it to filter your `series` to get the wanted values:

```
df[np.close(df['WAP'], 8.49)]
```

This will return you the `DataFrame` that contain only the rows where WAP is 8.49.

Answer (score 0):

```
wap = df['WAP']
wap = [float(x) for x in wap] #    lets make sure type is correct


for x in wap:
    while x < 8.49:
       print(x)
       break
    else:
       print('we hit it')
       break
```

This should stop while 8.49 is approached.